# Ansible to update HKEY on azure batch node

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-batch

As a part of ansible workflow , I am looking to update an azure batch pool windows images on runtime with ansible to disable windows update

I have created a azure batch node :

```
- name: Create Batch Account
  azure_rm_batchaccount:
      resource_group: MyResGroup
      name: mybatchaccount
      location: eastus
      auto_storage_account:
      name: mystorageaccountname
      pool_allocation_mode: batch_service
```

I know for a fact I can use Start task in azure batch node and execute the a cmd to change Hkey to NoUpdate = 1 .

I have an ansible snippet ready :

```
- name: "Ensure 'Configure Automatic Updates' is set to 'Disabled'"
  win_regedit:
    path: HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windowsupdate\Au
    name: "NoAutoUpdate"
    data: "1"
    type: dword
```

I would like to execute it on a run time in azure batch pool.
Does any one know how can this be archived with ansible ?

Answer (score 0):

To run something on boot in a Batch pool you should simply include it as part of your start task (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/pool/add#starttask).

In this instance however you likely should just make use of the Azure functionality to turn off automatic updates https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/pool/add#windowsconfiguration